# Using custom point markers in Matlab Mapping Toolbox

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to create custom point markers (from some image files) in Matlab with Mapping Toolbox.

So far, I didn't find anything about this in their documentation. Online searches only yielded:

> No. The marker shapes are hard-coded and you cannot add new ones. If you want a custom 
>   marker, then at each point you want the marker, you will have to use line() or 
>   equivalent to draw the marker or image() or equivalent to draw in an image.

(Source: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/4fe4e31f191f7080)

PS: I also cross-posted this to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/using-custom-point-markers-in-matlab-mapping-toolbox

Answer (score 0):

How about this? [Image Markers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1357): Plots an image and superimposes a binary image as a colored marker.